# Strange overflow layout in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Recently I am writing a chatroom by reactjs and I found out the behavior of my code is different on firefox and chrome browser.

This is the layout in chrome: 
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6miy1.png)

This is the layout in Firefox:
[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUnhb.png)

This is the css for the message layout

```
.messages{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    .message{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        margin: 15px;
        .message-user-image{
            img{
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        }
        .message-body{
            padding-left: 10px;
            .message-author{

            }
            .message-text{
                background: $body-color;
                color: #FFF;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
        }

        &.me{
            justify-content: flex-start;
            .message-body{
                .message-text{
                    background: $primary-color;
                    color: #FFF;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the html part

```
renderMessage(message){

        return <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: _.get(message, 'body')}} />
    }

<div className="content">
    <div className="messages">
        {messages.map((message, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index} className={classNames('message', {'me':message.me})}>                                                   
                    <div className="message-user-image">
                        <img src={message.avatar} alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="message-body">
                        <div className="message-author">
                            {message.me ? 'You ' : message.author} says: 
                        </div>
                        <div className="message-text">                                                       
                            {this.renderMessage(message)}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
</div>
```

And when I hit the send button in the area below the message part, I will update the container that store the message and force the component to update. Basically the margin of the messages just disappeared and stack up in chrome, but not the case in firefox.

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading the browser compatibility table correctly on MDN, but I think chrome needs a chrome specific prefix for `flex-direction` and `flex` value of `display` - though, perhaps whatever processor you're using for what you incorrectly call `CSS` does that for you - hard to say, because it's not CSS, but you don't say what it is

Comment: Using chrome developer tool, you can check it out how exactly it is rendering as html and also you can check which style got applied. Compare both firefox and chrome and you will get idea. otherwise post those html codes we can try from our end.